# How to update add/replace an entire database using Doctrine or Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, git, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a web-app project, for a trading company, which would like to have an offline access to the web App and possibility to update when connected to the net again.

The interface is easy to use offline - any php server will do with a local clone of the web app. The problem is the *database* update:

**Components :**
I will have 2 things to update :

- the mysql database
- the "downloaded pictures" that will eventually exist (i'm using [imperavi redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) as a text editor, and will download any image to a local folder that will have to synchronize as well. *That part is pretty easy i'll just have to add new files...*

The bigger problem comes from the database update: there are several users (between 6 and 10), and i'm trying to think of a way to update by adding new entries and replacing existing ones, like a replicated database but working on a git-like system : adds are added, updates are handled.

I can't see how to use replication as there is no server online, the sync has to be on demand.

Any tips ? The not-prefered solution would be to check every table an every entry, but i guess it's not the best way.

By the way, i'm using Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine 2, if you have any hint using these frameworks it would be great, thanks !

Comment: Will updates be happening on both the online and the offline systems concurrently, or can you "freeze" the online database while the offline one is being used?

Comment: Both of them i guess, the system must be able to handle offline edition and then a sync. But every user has definited entries so there doesn't have to be any conflict between users.

Comment: Do the same users exist in the "live web" version and the offline version, or are they separate users?

Answer (score 0):

**Real recommendation**

I would advise you to dig into this requirement with your client. Do they really need this, or do they just think so?

Implementing it will add significant complexity to your project, and there may be better alternatives that will fulfil the client's actual needs. For example, can they purchase a cheap cellular modem and use it to connect to the main application?

**If records stand on their own**

If you're collecting the kind of data that could be done via several physical clipboards, e.g. collecting names and email addresses of people at a conference, simply add a column to your database indicating the source of the record and make it part of your primary key.

**If records depend on other data in the database**

Instead of storing updates in a copy of your primary database, consider recording a transaction queue in the disconnected application. This will let you replay the transactions in order on the central database during reconnect.

Without knowing what types of transactions you will be doing, consider this possible transaction queue for a simple banking application (written in English; you'll need a good format for this, and one that probably stores more information):

```
- Deposit USD 100.00 to account 12345, received at 2014-01-01T12:00:00
- Deposit CAD 50.23 to account 55555, received at 2014-01-01T12:00:03
- Withdraw USD 25.00 from account 12345, received at 2014-01-01T15:00:00
```

This has several implications:

- Your disconnected application will have a different architecture to your main one
- You will not be able to provide reliable feedback for certain operations on the disconnected application

  - E.g., during the withdrawal above, how do we know that account 12345 contains at least $25? What if the account was emptied out using the main application while we were disconnected?
- During synchronization, the replayed transactions may generate errors that need to be handled and possibly acted upon

  - E.g., overdraft might generate a fee; account 55555 has been closed, so we need to track the owner down
- Updates from the disconnected application should probably be treated as if they are received at the time of synchronization, not the time they were entered into the disconnected application

  - But how does this affect the system? Consider exchange rates in the example above; which rate do you guarantee your client, the one at the time of "deposit" via the disconnected app or the one at the time of replay? Does it matter which is a better rate?
- What happens if you go a long time between data syncs?
- Keep *really good logs*, because it's just a matter of time before you'll be digging through them trying to track down some inconsistencies

This becomes even more difficult to manage if you have multiple copies of the offline application, e.g. if Bobby and Sue both take a copy to a conference and independently collect data to be replayed later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm about to call the client to discuss this point, but at the moment : 
- notes are basically text + pictures and graphs
- the "offline" aspect is for moments like train, or even underground trains, where there is no data connection at all...so offline syncs will not be regular events.